# What does it mean when in graphstudio there is no error when connection two filter but they have not been connected

Tags: c++, directshow

When I attempt to connect two filters in graphstudio that don't match i get usually an error code.
In my case however if i try to connect my filter to another filter there is no error message nor
has a connection been made e.g. there is no arrow between the filters.

This is how filters connect according to the documentation

> The general outline of the connectio n process is the following:
>
> 1. The Filter Graph Manager calls IPin::Connect on the output pin, passing a pointer to the input pin.
> 2. If the output pin accepts the connection, it calls IPin::ReceiveConnection on the input pin.
> 3. If the input pin also accepts the connection, the connection attempt succeeds and the pins are connected.

Using Visual Studio i can assure that ReceiveConnection returns S_OK

So there must be something more thant just these 3 steps, otherwise it should work

Comment: You could save weeks of your time by using the base classes provided in the SDK (like CBaseFilter, CBaseOutputPin etc.), but even if you resist to using them, just look at their source code in SDK DirectShow samples (see BaseClasses folder) to learn what really should happen during the connection. For example, does your filter choose/create a right allocator for its samples?

Answer (score 0):

Pin connection is basically a `IGraphBuilder::Connect` call with internal calls to `IPin::Connect` and `IPin::ReceiveConnection` on the filters in question. The call succeeds if the internal calls succeed.

Later on, GraphStudio enumerates pins and checks pin connections on these pins. If a pin does not report anything connected on it, then GraphStudio displays disconnection.

Talking into consideration your earlier questions about overriding `Connect` methods, I suppose you overrode them wrong: you don't do the connection on your filter/pin, still you return success code as the operation status.